# socket.io emit/broadcast to every client

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I can not find out how to emit from the client or an other NodeJS file to every client.
Emitting to the server worked, but not to every other client.

Servercode:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(8080));

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('playerData', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Clientcode:

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.5.js"></script> 
<script>
var socket = io('http://localhost:8080');
socket.on('playerData', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
</script>
```

I am using Node.JS - Jade, Express, Socket.io (and AngularJS, but not in this part of the code)

The Serverside console.log is being called when I call my emit function, but on the Clientside nothing happens.
Currently using Chrome as my browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to emit from the client to the server and then broadcast that message from the server to each client.